# Using COM from an F# script

Tags: f#, com

How do I use COM libraries from an F# script?  Is it even possible?  How do I reference the required COM libraries in an .fsx file?

More specifically, I'd like to use InstallShield Automation from a build script.  Despite all my efforts, I could only get it to work with a regular compiled project.

**Edit:** I already tried the [COM type provider project](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.ComProvider/index.html).  However, it doesn't seem to find any types in the particular COM library I'm interested in.  If it's a bug or intended behavior, I don't know.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. The OP is not asking for us to debug his problem he is looking for how it is done. This is a valid question and as far as I can tell is a new one for the F# tag. If I knew the answer or had the time to research it I would answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think possibly maybe the [COM type provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.ComProvider/) might help you out:

> One advantage of this method is that you can author and deploy F#
>   scripts without having to pre-generate the interop assemblies. Another
>   advantage is that you can easily explore all the COM components
>   installed on your machine via intellisense.

And yes I did just [google it](https://www.google.no/?q=COM%20interop%20f%23), which OP also might have done before asked here.

Comment: I should have added to my question that I already tried using this very project. I didn't have any luck with it because it didn't find any types in the assemblies I depend on, however. I'm not sure if that's a bug if the COM type provider or if it's intended behavior.

Comment: @SammyS. is it possible to add what you are trying to do? some code? some actuall reference to some COM/DLL/anything? there are limitations mentioned like Office-COMs are not at all supported: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.ComProvider#limitations-and-known-issues

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. I still accepted your answer since I believe the PIA limitation might prevent the COM provider from working. I ended up creating a separate assembly which directly accesses the COM assemblies.  I can then load this assembly from a script.